# How to leverage affinity propagation using sklearn for large dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, tf-idf

I used to affinity propagation for creating clusters for my dataset, my dataset is pretty huge. I converted my dataset which is text to vectors using tfidf and then fit into affinity propagation. For the smaller dataset affinity works seamlessly, however, for the large dataset it starts consuming a hell lot of RAM and finally, my OS kills the process. I did a lot of research and found few StackOverflow, it said using np.medien or np.mean etc.. but didn't work for my problem. I also principle analyse component and try to reduce the matrix, still consumed a lot of RAM. 
I came across leveraging affinity propagation - This addresses large data sets by doing randomly selected points for similarity rather than an NXN, but couldn't find in sklearn or python. 
I saw it R language.
[enter link description here](https://rdrr.io/cran/apcluster/man/apclusterL-methods.html)

How do we do it in python where I am using affinity propagation from sklearn.

Here is my piece of code of affinity what I am trying.

```
    def affinity_cluster_technique(self, preference=None, X_train_vecs=None, filenames=None, contents=None):
    """

    :param preference:
    :param X_train_vecs:
    :param vectorizer:
    :param filenames:
    :param contents:
    :return:
    """
    logger.info('Into the affinity core engine having the preference {}'.format(str(preference)))
    if X_train_vecs!=None or X_train_vecs!='None':
        X = X_train_vecs
        # X = cosine_distances(X)



        # svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=100)
        # normalizer = Normalizer(copy=False)
        # lsa = make_pipeline(svd, normalizer)
        # X= X_train_vecs = lsa.fit_transform(X_train_vecs)

        # X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
        logger.info("The shape of X_train after the lsa {}".format(X_train_vecs.shape))
        # X = X_train_vecs.toarray()
        # X = np.array(X)
        logger.info('Vector to array of the X data processed')
        if preference!='None':
            af = AffinityPropagation(damping=0.5, preference=preference,verbose=True)
        else:
            af = AffinityPropagation(damping=0.5, preference=None,verbose=True)
        logger.info('The affinity propagation object is {}'.format(str(af)))
        y = af.fit_predict(X)
        exemplars = af.cluster_centers_
        number_of_clusters = af.labels_.tolist()

        # logger.info("The total number of cluster Affinity generated is: {}".format(str(len(exemplars))))
        data = {'filename': filenames, 'contents': contents, 'cluster_label': number_of_clusters}
        frame = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=[number_of_clusters], columns=['filename', 'contents', 'cluster_label'])
        logger.info('Sample of the clustered df {}'.format(str(frame.head(2))))
        cluster_and_count_of_docs = frame['cluster_label'].value_counts(sort=True, ascending=False)
        dict_of_cluster_and_filename = dict()

        for i in number_of_clusters:
            list_of_file_id = list()
            list_of_files_in_cluster = list()
            list_of_files_in_cluster = frame.ix[i]['filename'].tolist()
            try:
                for file_id in list_of_files_in_cluster:
                    list_of_file_id.append(file_id)
                dict_of_cluster_and_filename['clusters ' + str(i)] = list_of_file_id
            except Exception as e:
                list_of_file_id.append(list_of_files_in_cluster)
                dict_of_cluster_and_filename['clusters ' + str(i)] = list_of_file_id

        return dict_of_cluster_and_filename, X, y, exemplars
    else:
        try:
            raise Exception
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("The X_train data is None {}".format(str(e)))
        return dict(),None,None,None
```

Please let me know if I am doing something worng... and help out figure out how to achive for large dataset.

Comment: Affinity propagation needs 2 matrixes of n x n entries. This algorithm will never be scalable. If you have large data, use something else.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic here. Try to implement the algorithm you want *yourself*!

Comment: @Niteshkumar: Were you able to get the fix of the above problem. I am also working on affinity propagation problem. Currently its on toy input. But subsequently I have to implement it on 120K+ strings. May face the same problem.